# Raspberry Pi Pico: Input Not Working as Expected

Tags: pi-pico

I was following the Pico tutorial and got stuck on the inputs part as my Pico does not show value 1 even when the button is pressed the outputs are working fine, I continued and got stuck again on potentiometers as the value is always around 28,000 even when the potentiometer is not connected please help as i am a beginner to this.
[image]

> > > from machine import Pin
> > > button = Pin(14 , Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)
> > > button.value()
> > > 0
> > > button.value()
> > > 0
> > > button.value()
> > > 0
> > > button.value()
> > > 0
> > > [image]
> > > [image]

Comment: some breadboards have a break in the middle of the + and - lines. Can you post a photo of your setup pls

Comment: your circuit does not contain a potentiomer ... it contains a variable resistor

Comment: It is connected I checked and the circuit is exactly as shown on the figure please help.

Comment: how can we help if you don't give the info we ask for?

Comment: I'm sorry i took apart the bottom of bread board to check..
the photos are added to the question

Comment: What do you mean by "the value is always around 28,000"? Your code appears to be using the pin as a digital pin rather than an analog input. Please provide a link to the tutorial you are following.

Comment: I don't see where the ground from the power supply is located. Please show us a color picture from the top so the picture looks like like the schematic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "not working as expected". You have ADC0 pin connected to 3.3V via a potentiometer, so I would expect to read quasi-constant some non-zero value corresponding to that voltage level from the ADC. Even if you disconnect the potentiometer, the ADC0 pin may still stay at 3.3V, delivering the same value.

If you want to make a voltage divider, you need to connect the side terminals of the pot to 3.3V and GND, and the voltage on the middle terminal will then be proportional to the pot position.